# Using flex: 1 to expand the div will collapse everything in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I used this guide to make my footer stick to the bottom : http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

This guide use flex box to do the job. It worked perfectly on Chrome and Firefox and even on Edge. But on IE11, all the elements collapse on each other like in this image :

[image: Flex1]

Code demo :

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}
.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <div id="react-root">
    <div class="container">
      <main class="Site-content">Site</main>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: IE11 as per http://caniuse.com/#search=flex  still has partial support for flexbox so this might be the reason for the issue but as your layout is simple you should attempt it without flexbox..

Comment: @DhavalChheda Actually i want to stick the footer to the bottom. I used other techniques including setting the footer to the bottom. But all of them had issues. One method kept the footer in the bottom but when the content overflow, the footer goes on-top of them. The biggest issues is since I use React in the real site, the content and the footer won't be direct children of the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use following to make it working for IE11:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Full Code:

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.Site {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}
.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <main class="Site-content">Site</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**[Working Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tpufc06L/3/)**

Comment: Sorry. I just tried it in the sample and it worked. But in the site it didn't. Then I realized that in the site the footer and the content sit inside two other divs because I'm using react. If i move them to be direct children of body tag, it will work. But can't do it. Sorry, I just updated the code with what I have in my real site.

Comment: @THpubs give `height:100%` to `.container`.

Comment: It works but if the content go beyond the footer, the content will overlap. I just updated the code... try to resize the browser window and make it small and let the content overlap the footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
        .Site {
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: green;
        }

        main {
            height: calc(100% - 50px);
            background-color: red;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: blue;
            height: 50px;
        }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the IE known bug. You can not use min-height and flexbox at the same time. Please refer https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview

Try to update your IE or height instead of min-height, also try to avoid vh. I think that will work for you.

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Site {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}
.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if the content go beyond the footer, the content will overlap. I just updated the code... try to re-size the browser window and make it small and let the content overlap the footer.